# React child componet is not rendering in main component

Tags: reactjs, components

I'm new to reactjs and I'm facing some issues while creating a simple react app. The child component is not rendering to main component. I'm not getting any console error, but the child component UI is not getting displayed in main component.I have a child component like below

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

var NavBar = React.createClass({

render: function () {

    return (
        <div className="navbar navbar-default">
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="navbar-header pull-left">
                            <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li className="active"><a>Home<span className="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div className="navbar-header pull-right">
                            <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li className="dropdown">
                                    <a id="userAdsId" className="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Welcome, Bibin</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
    )

}

});

module.exports = NavBar
```

below is the main component

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

var navbar = require('./navBar');

ReactDOM.render(<navbar/>,document.getElementById('ContactForm'))
```

Anyone please help

Comment: If @Mayanak answer solves the problem, can you accept it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is in this line:

`var navbar = require('./navBar');`

Instead of the use this:

`var Navbar = require('./navBar');`

It will work.

**Reason**: In `JSX`, lower-case names are considered as `HTML` tags. So Its a rule that all `React` `components` must start with a upper case letter.

Comment: Thanks for the help